# How to tell VSCode debugger to reload a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

as you can see in the Picture the debugger thinks that there is an error on line 13. But I removed the line saved the file and tried to restart the program but the Debugger still thinks that there is something wrong.

Can Somebody tell me how to reload a file in VSCode?

[image: The Problem!!]

Comment: What do you mean by "reaload a file"? If anything; you should do a Clean and rebuild of project/solution to get rid of old built code.

Comment: Dotnet still thinks that there is an error on line 13. But i already updated the src file and removed the line but that didn't worked. how can i tell dotnet to use this file and not just the file that is somewhere temporary stored. Also this seems to be the Debuggers fault because when i run dotnet run it works just fine.

Comment: This is what a Project/Solution Clean function is for. I never encountered anyone "telling" debugger anything...

Comment: I think you didnt quiet understand what the problem was but thank you for your help. The problem was that VSCode first compiles a file and then executes this file .

Comment: Vs Code didn't executed the file that was compiled. This happend because I switched the framework from dotnet core to .Net 4.7.2 .

Comment: My apologies, I missed VS-Code part, I thought we're talking about VS.

Comment: No Problem thank you for your time you gave me the kick to think in another direction.